# change master ip address --apiserver-advertise-address

Tags: kubernetes

How do you change ip address of the master or any worker node

I have experimented with:

```
kubeadm init --control-plane-endpoint=cluster-endpoint --apiserver-advertise-address=<x.x.x.x>
```

And then I guess I need the new config with the right certificate:

```
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf ~/.kube/config
```

I tried the following suggested from Hajed.Kh:

Changed ip address in:

```
etcd.yaml (contained ip)
kube-apiserver.yaml (contained ip)
kube-controller-manager.yaml (not this one?
kube-scheduler.yaml (not this one?)
```

But I still get the same ip address in:

```
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf ~/.kube/config
```

Answer (score 4):

The  `apiserver-advertise-address` flag is located in the api-server manifest file and all Kubernetes components manifests are located here `/etc/kubernetes/manifest/`.Those are realtime updated files so change and save and it will be redeployed instantally :

```
etcd.yaml
kube-apiserver.yaml
kube-controller-manager.yaml
kube-scheduler.yaml
```

For the worker I think it will automatically update changes while the kubelet is connected to the api-server.

Comment: But some parameters are only configurable during cluster bootstrapping.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65995056/kubernetes-api-server-bind-address-vs-advertise-address